# Is it possible to prevent Auto-Translate in google translate without preventing translation?

Tags: google-translate

I ran into an interesting issue on a rails website that I'm developing today.  It's the front end for a sports facility, and includes team pages that show the schedule for a team as well as their standings.

As I browsed to an arbitrary team page today using Chrome, auto translation kicked in, indicating that the page was in Spanish, and Chrome was translating it to English.  This was a bit of a surprise to me, since I wrote the web site, and it's not in Spanish.

However, this was a team page for a team named "Los Muchachos Blancos".  The presence of the team name seemed sufficient to trigger a translation, turning the page into a team page for "White Boys".  While this is amusing, I'm not sure it's something that the customers will appreciate.

I realize that I can either suppress translation entirely by using the tag

```
<meta name="google" value="notranslate">
```

on the page, or by assigning an element to be of class="notranslate".  However, I'm not really looking to completely disable the translation, just to prevent an automatic translation simply because some of the teams have Spanish names.  I'd like to avoid having to tag every team name as class "notranslate" anywhere it's displayed.  I need to support translation, since they do have Spanish speaking customers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell Google Translate to not translate a section of a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628507/how-can-i-tell-google-translate-to-not-translate-a-section-of-a-website)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to deactivate translation offers alltogether from Chrome. I analyzed the file containing Chrome's seetings, which can be found here:
%appdatalocal%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences

Substituting "translate":{"enabled":true} with "translate":{"enabled":false} (found at character 130.233 - allmost at the end), stops Chrome from translating.

If you need to automate this on a larger number of clients, you can use this powershell script:
((Get-Content -path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\preferences" -Raw) -replace '"translate":{"enabled":true}','"translate":{"enabled":false}') | Set-Content -path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\preferences"
Have fun.