# HTML: Setup a div as not google translatable

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

I have this page with book titles and author names. I'd like those two elements to remain untouched when the user accepts google proposal to translate the page.

How do I tell google translate to avoid certain elements of the page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628507/how-can-i-tell-google-translate-to-not-translate-a-section-of-a-website

Comment: @pawel Yes, I marked my question (witch did not come up in my searches or in the Q title input field) as dupli. myself :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add class to your element `notranslate`

eg:

```
<div class="notranslate set_bold_text"> lorem epsom</div>
</br>
<div class="set_bold_text" > lorem epsom</div>
```

the above div wont be affected to translation to your selected language but the below div will be translated

Answer (score 4):

Two options to try:

- either add class=notranslate to the element
- or HTML5 translate="no" attribute

As per: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_translate.asp