# Google Translate only Content <div class="site-content">

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

and I want my site to have a Translator where only the single content will be translate. It is possible to translate only the 1 div? Default English and I want it to translate in Chinese.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({includedLanguages: 'en,zh-CN'}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Because you can use the "class=notranslate" on everything you do not want translated. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628507/how-can-i-tell-google-translate-to-not-translate-a-section-of-a-website)