# How can I disable browser default helper popup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser

I want to open custom bottom sheet when I select text. But browsers have a default helper popup on mobile.I want to remove default browser pop up. How can I do it?

[image: Remove browser default popup]

Comment: When does this open? After you select some text from the screen?

Comment: yes. I do this with selectionchange event listener.

Comment: How about disabling the text selection and having custom popup/popover on click/tap?

Comment: no. I need a pop up for translate. It will translate text after select

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629628/1746830 Let me know if this helps.

Comment: it didn't help me. I tried it but I still see helper pop-ups.