# Firestore Translate Text Extension - Conditional translations & dynamic languages

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-extensions

I am trying to use `firebase/firestore-translate-text@0.1.8` - the Firebase extension for GCloud Translate API. I am missing 2 things, I'll fill in a request but in case there is some workaround, going to ask here first:

**USE CASE:**
Clients type information in the app. Certain fields need translations, but translations are conditional upon two factors.

1. **User has enabled/disabled translations.** *(How to ignore translations if user hasn't enabled translations?)*
2. **The supported languages as per user.** *(I didn't find a way to pass dynamic array of languages, they need to be set up at installation step)*

In my case, I will have a user document under users collection where storing preferences like `languages: [en, es, fr, de]` and `isTranslationEnabled: true` and those can be used by the listener somehow to either trigger or not, and to use the langs.

Extension: https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-translate-text

**EXTRA:** Is possible to translate the already existing content? instead of going one by one to update -> triggers the translation

Btw, this is a great extension that works fantastic, I am just missing those features to fulfill my requirements, it doesn't mean it doesn't yours. By other hand, I think this features might be commonly used/needed among others. Thanks Firebase Team!

Comment: You may check these links, [Configurations and settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628507/how-can-i-tell-google-translate-to-not-translate-a-section-of-a-website) and [Google Dcoumentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq#technical_questions)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Maybe I wasn’t so clear about the question, what you pointed out is about the translation tool that google/browser gives you. What I am asking is about firestore translation extension. They aren’t related.

Comment: Please share any documentation you are following for this.

Comment: I just added a link to the doc. https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-translate-text. @GouravB

Comment: After going through your question and the use cases you mentioned this seems to be a feature request that needs implementation. You may raise this issue at firebase [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues) to add the features you listed that might be commonly used/ needed among others.

Comment: Hey @VaidehiJamankar - do you think I can report it in the extensions repository? https://github.com/firebase/extensions - and you know if I could contribute? Would be great if you can point me to the right direction/person. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can raise a feature request [here](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=fr.md). And, the contributors link is [this](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/f053443834d5ef4521100966d16367799e8340b8/CONTRIBUTING.md)